# Can I change the zoom level in tor browser (without affecting anonymity)?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Most websites have a small default letter size. If I change zoom level with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, does it happen entirely on my computer?

I know window size shouldn't be changed for anonymity reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** due to [users comment](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/can-i-change-the-zoom-level-in-tor-browser-without-affecting-anonymity?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment14025_9614) and clarification:

---

to be accurate, you asked 2 different questions:

- *If I change zoom level with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, does it happen entirely on my computer?*
  yes, zooming should be done entirely on your computer (like the normal rendering)<s>, but i'm not sure if it can be used afterwards to "increase your uniqueness"...</s>.
- *Can I change the zoom level in tor browser (without affecting anonymity)?*
  no, [it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser) that the **zoom level can be used to "increase your uniqueness"**!

Comment: Seems like zomming works just like increasing `@media` size regarding CSS. See f.ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223866/media-queries-for-different-zoom-levels-of-browser. it seems as though your comment to http://tor.stackexchange.com/a/9610/5234 applies as well. :-(

Comment: @user: thank you for the investigation and the link!

Comment: If you need to zoom in on text, you might consider using a desktop application like the GNOME Zoom options: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/a11y-mag.html this should avoid being detectable from inside the browser, at the cost of being slightly less well integrated into the browser in general.